# `illegalargumentexception` being thrown when creating a notification channel

Tags: android-studio, exception, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

I am trying to add a notification alarm to my app and I keep getting an error that I can't seem to figure out. It's the `illegalargumentexception` and it is being thrown on `notificationManagerager.createNotificationChannel(channel);` I have no idea what it is wanting me to fix. I have looked at a bunch of tutorials online and I can't seem to figure out what is causing this issue. Please help me.

I'm working with API 26.

```
package com.example.mytermtracker.notifications;


import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.mytermtracker.R;
import com.example.mytermtracker.application.Date;

public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "app: CustomReceiver";

    private static int id = 0;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "com.example.mytermtracker";

    public static final String TEST_CHANEL = "";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: " + Date.now().toSQL());
        String channelName = intent.getStringExtra("channel_name");
        if (channelName == null) channelName = "";

        String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
        if (title == null) title = "";

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        if (message == null) message = "";

        String description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
        if (description == null) description = "";

        int lockScreenVisibility = intent.getIntExtra("lock_screen_visibility",
                                                      Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelName)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        channel.setLockscreenVisibility(lockScreenVisibility);

        NotificationManager notificationManagerager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (notificationManagerager != null) {
            notificationManagerager.createNotificationChannel(channel); //<====== Exception is being thrown on this line.
            notificationManagerager.notify(id++, notification);
        }
    }

    public enum Channel {
        C001 ("c001"),
        C002 ("c002")
        ;

        private String name;

        Channel(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    public static Builder create(Context context, Channel channel, Date triggerTime) {
        return new Builder(context, channel, triggerTime);
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Context context;
        private Channel channel;
        private Date triggerTime;
        private String title;
        private String message;
        private String description;
        private int lockScreenVisibility;

        private Builder(Context context, Channel channel, Date triggerTime) {
            this.context = context;
            this.channel = channel;
            this.triggerTime = triggerTime;
            this.title = "";
            this.message = "";
            this.description = "";
            this.lockScreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC;
        }

        public Builder setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setLockScreenVisibility(int lockScreenVisibility) {
            this.lockScreenVisibility = lockScreenVisibility;
            return this;
        }

        public void done() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, CustomReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra("channel", channel.name);
            intent.putExtra("title", title);
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            intent.putExtra("description", description);
            intent.putExtra("lock_screen_visibility", lockScreenVisibility);

            Log.d(TAG, "done: " + Date.now().toSQL());

            PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent
                    .getBroadcast(context, id++, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Log.d(TAG, "done: trigger: " + triggerTime.toSQL());

            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `channelName` at the `NotificationChannel` instantiation? I would imagine an empty `String` is invalid.

Comment: Yeah. That seems to have fixed it.

Comment: If I'm understanding your design correctly, the problem appears to stem from the fact that you never put a `"channel_name"` extra on the `Intent` in your `Builder`.

Comment: That was the issue. I originally just had the word "channel", in both spots, but then I just changed it in the top section, but not the other section.